# Matrix Calculus: $\nabla_{\mathbf{c}}(-2\mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{D} \mathbf{c} + \mathbf{c}^T \mathbf{c}) = -2\mathbf{D}^T \mathbf{x} + 2\mathbf{c}$?

Tags: matrices, partial-derivative, vector-analysis, matrix-calculus

In an example of Principle Component Analysis, my textbook uses vector calculus to do the following:

> $\nabla_{\mathbf{c}}(-2\mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{D} \mathbf{c} + \mathbf{c}^T \mathbf{c}) = \mathbf{0}$
>
> $\rightarrow -2\mathbf{D}^T \mathbf{x} + 2\mathbf{c} = \mathbf{0}$
>
> $\rightarrow c = \mathbf{D}^T \mathbf{x}$

Where $\nabla_{\mathbf{c}}$ is the gradient with respect to $\mathbf{c}$, $\mathbf{D} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times l}$, $\mathbf{c} \in \mathbb{R}^l$, and the columns of $\mathbf{D}$ are orthogonal to each other.

I have the following questions:

1. How did the authors get from $\mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{D} \mathbf{c}$ to $\mathbf{D}^T \mathbf{x}$? I haven't studied matrix calculus, but I'm assuming that $\dfrac{ \partial }{\partial{\mathbf{c}}} \mathbf{c} = I$? What about $\mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{D}$ to $\mathbf{D}^T \mathbf{x}$?
2. How did the authors go from $\mathbf{c}^T \mathbf{c}$ to $2\mathbf{c}$? I found the following in *[Matrix Differentiation](https://atmos.washington.edu/%7Edennis/MatrixCalculus.pdf)* by Randal J. Barnes:

---

[image]

---

If we assume that $\mathbf{A} = I$, then isn't this what we're looking for? But wouldn't that leave us with $2\mathbf{c}^T$ instead of just $2\mathbf{c}$?

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to clarify this.

Comment: The gradient of the inner product $\langle \mathbf a, \mathbf x \rangle$ with respect to $\bf x$ is $\bf a$. This answers your 1st question.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Thanks for the response. I don’t understand what the inner product has to do with this?

Comment: $\mathbf{x}^\top \mathbf{D} \,\mathbf{c} = \langle \mathbf D^\top \mathbf x, \mathbf c \rangle$.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo So you're saying that $\dfrac{ \partial }{\partial{\mathbf{c}}} \mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{D} \mathbf{c} = \mathbf{D}^T \mathbf{x}$?

Comment: Yes, indeed I am.

Comment: My two cents, in addition to Rodrigodo's comment: I prefer to differentiate with respect to $(\cdot)^T$, i.e., $\mathbf{c}^T$ in your case such that one can obtain the result without any transpose per se. So, $\frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{c}^T} \left[ -2\mathbf{c}^T \left( \mathbf{D}^T \mathbf{x}\right)  + \mathbf{c}^T\mathbf{c} \right] = -2 \mathbf{D}^T \mathbf{x} + 2\mathbf{c} $.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are (unfortunately) different conventions in matrix calculus.
The most common is 
$$\nabla_{c} \equiv \frac{\partial}{\partial c}$$
However, in you example the convention is
$$\nabla_{c} \equiv \frac{\partial}{\partial c^{T}}$$
With this in mind, we perform the calculation
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial c^{T}}\left(-2x^{T}Dc + c^{T}c\right) = 0 \tag{1}\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial c^{T}}\left(-2c^{T}D^{T}x + c^{T}c\right) = 0 \tag{2}\\
-2\frac{\partial c^{T}}{\partial c^{T}}D^{T}x + \frac{\partial}{\partial c^{T}}(c^{T}c) = 0 \tag{3}\\
-2D^{T}x + \frac{\partial c^{T}}{\partial c^{T}}c + c^{T}\frac{\partial c}{\partial c^{T}}= 0 \tag{4}\\
-2D^{T}x + c + c^{T}\frac{\partial c}{\partial c^{T}}= 0 \tag{5}\\
-2D^{T}x + 2c= 0 \tag{6}
\end{align*}

Now, to get from from $(5)$ to $(6)$ we need to show that $\displaystyle c^{T}\frac{\partial c}{\partial c^{T}} = c$.

We can see this using index notation. Here, $c$ has an upper index, and $c^{T}$ has a lower index. They are related by $c^{i} = \delta^{ij}(c^{T})_{j}$ and $(c^{T})_{i} = \delta_{ij}c^{j}$ (where $\delta$ is the kronecker delta).

So we have
$$\left(c^{T}\frac{\partial c}{\partial c^{T}}\right)^j
= (c^{T})_{i}\frac{\partial c^{i}}{\partial (c^{T})_j}\\
= (c^{T})_{i}\frac{\partial (c^{T})_{k}\delta^{ki}}{\partial (c^{T})_j}\\
= (c^{T})_{i}\frac{\partial (c^{T})_{k}}{\partial (c^{T})_j}\delta^{ki}\\
= (c^{T})_{i}\delta^{j}_{k}\delta^{ki} = (c^{T})_{i}\delta^{ji} = c^{j}
$$

And we are done.

Comment: Thanks for the response. In the second part, you substituted $c^i = (c^{T})_{k}\delta^{ki}$, but, since you said that $c^{i} = \delta^{ij}(c^{T})_{j}$, shouldn't it be $(c^{T})_{k}\delta^{ik}$?

Comment: Oh, the [Kronecker deltas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta) are defined by
$$\delta^{ij} = \begin{cases}1&i=j\\0&i\neq j\end{cases}$$
hence they are symmetric.

If you represent the objects with upper indices by column matrices, and the objects with lower indices by lower indices, you get that indeed $(c^{T})_{i}$ and $c^{j}$ are the transposes of each other, $\delta^{ij}$ turns row matrices into column matrices, $\delta_{ij}$ turns column matrices into row matrices, and $\delta^{i}_{j}$ is the identity matrix.

Comment: I understand now. Thank you very much for the clarification.

Comment: You're welcome. You can [read more here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus) about the different conventions in matrix calculus.

Comment: I meant *...the objects with lower indices by row matrices...*

Answer (score 0):

One can define the gradient $\nabla f$ of a (nice) scalar function $f$ as the unique vector valued function such that
$$ f(x+v) = f(x) + \nabla f(x)^Tv + o(|v|) \qquad (|v|\to 0)$$
From this, one can prove the following basic results-

1. If $f(x)$ is a linear map given by matrix multiplication $f(x) = Ax$ then its gradient is constant in $x$, with value $\nabla f(x) =A^T$.
2. If $f(x) = x^TAx$ then $\nabla f(x) =  (A^T+A)x $.

I would say these are good exercises if you haven't worked with derivatives much. These together give the result.

A remark about the result you found in Barnes's book: he is using a different convention,
$$f(x+v) = f(x) + \tilde\nabla f(x) v + o(|v|)$$
and these are of course related by transposition of matrices. But you should take note which convention you are using when looking at other resources.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have a few questions: [...]

Comment: 1. What is $o(|v|) \qquad (|v|\to 0)$? Is that supposed to be "little o" notation? I'm familiar with "big O" notation.

Comment: 2. Why is your result for $\nabla f(x) =  (A^T+A)x$ different from that of Barnes? How did you come to this conclusion instead of his $x^T(A^T+A)$?

Comment: @ThePointer 1 yes, we say $f = o(g)$ as $v\to S$ if $\lim_{v\to S} f/g = 0$. You can think of it as 'going to zero faster than $g$', and for many nice functions its almost the same as $O(|v|^2)$.

Comment: @ThePointer 2. See remark at bottom of answer.

Comment: 3. What is the difference between your convention $f(x+v) = f(x) + \nabla f(x)^Tv + o(|v|) \qquad (|v|\to 0)$ and that of Barnes $f(x+v) = f(x) + \tilde\nabla f(x) v + o(|v|)$? Why the $\tilde$ above the gradient?

Comment: The `\tilde` and the one without, those are *defining* equations for the functions in question. So it matters not what notation one chooses. If I wanted to match Barnes's notation exactly I would have used $\partial / \partial x$, but I feared you would think you already knew what this was. Using a different symbol makes it more unfamiliar to you, so that you won't skip over it.

Comment: @ThePointer in different words: there is a choice to be made, namely is a gradient a row or a column vector? Barnes chose a row vector, so that $\tilde\nabla f(x)$ can naturally act on a vector as a matrix. Your PCA book chose a column vector, which acts on vectors via $\nabla f(x)^T v$. (a dot product)