# Gradient of the Rayleigh Quotient

Tags: derivatives, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-calculus

In the introduction part of the paper [The Fast Convergence of Incremental PCA](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/5132-the-fast-convergence-of-incremental-pca), the authors mention that the gradient of the Rayleigh quotient is equal to:

$$
\triangledown G(v) = \frac{2}{\|v\|^2}(A - \frac{v^{T}Av}{v^{T}v} I_d)v
$$

when the [Rayleigh quotient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_quotient) is: $$G(v) = \frac{v^{T}Av}{v^{T}v}$$

($v \in \mathbb{R}^d$ and $A \in \mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$)

What are the steps to derive the given value for $\triangledown G(v)$ ?

**EDIT:**

As suggested by @Alex R. in a comment, I tried to proceed using the identity for a derivative of a quotient. I don't know/remember the matrix calculus identities to proceed. Here's what I tried:

Let $N = v^{T}Av$ and $D = v^{T}v$,

Then, $G'(v) = \frac{N'D-ND'}{D^{2}} \tag{1}\label{eq1}$

$D^2$ can be written as $(v^{T}v)^2 = (\|v\|^{2})^2$.

Using $\frac{dx^{T}Ax}{dx} = x^{T}(A + A^{T})$, $N'$ can be written as $v^{T}(A+A^{T})$.

$D' = 2v^{T}$.

Plugging these values to $\eqref{eq1}$ yields:

$$
G'(v) = \frac{v^{T}(A+A^{T})v^{T}v - v^{T}Av(2v^{T})}{\|v\|^4}
$$

I can't figure out how to simplfy this. Any pointers to resources I should look are also appreciated.

Comment: Let $N(v) = v^TAv$ and $D(v) = v^Tv$. Then $\frac{dG}{dx}:=G'(v) = \frac{N'D-D'N}{D^2}$. Now just work out the individual derivatives.

Comment: @AlexR. Thanks, can you please have a look at my edit? It's been a long time since I did calculus and I have forgotten most of the simple things. Appreciate if you can point out a single resource (if there's any that you are aware of) where I can look up matrix calculus identities (nice if they have the derivations as well).

Comment: $(v^Tv)^2 = v^Tvv^Tv = \|v\|^{\displaystyle \color{red}{4}}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A covariance matrix is symmetric. Hence $A^T = A$. Thus

$$G'(v) = \frac{v^{T}(A+A^{T})v^{T}v - v^{T}Av(2v^{T})}{\|v\|^{\displaystyle \color{red}{4}}} 
=\frac{\color{green}{v^{T}}\color{blue}{(2A)}v^{T}v - (2\color{green}{v^{T} I_d})v^{T}Av}{\|v\|^{4}}
= 2\color{green}{v^T}\frac{A\|v\|^2 - I_dv^T Av}{\|v\|^4}= \frac{2v^T}{\|v\|^2}\left(A - \frac{v^TAv}{\|v\|^2}I_d\right) $$

which is exactly the result, after you realise that you and the author of the paper have used different conventions for gradient, see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2846427/matrix-calculus-nabla-mathbfc-2-mathbfxt-mathbfd-mathbfc-ma/2846458#2846458).

Comment: Thanks Calvin. Btw, do you have a recommendation for a good resource where I can refresh my matrix calculus? - There are just too many results on google.

Comment: @akilat90 Not really sorry, I learned most of it from Gonzalez and Stuart's continuum mechanics if that helps https://www.amazon.com/Continuum-Mechanics-Cambridge-Applied-Mathematics/dp/0521714249